# Case Assignement Rules

Tags: queue, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have an assignment rule on case object
If the criteria meets the case owner name  will be a **queue**( which has 10 users)
Now how can i know among the ten users who have picked up the case and how does the other users can know that the case has been picked up by x user

Answer (score 0):

Train users that if they pick some work from the queue - they need to first claim it (change owner to themselves). There's big "Change Owner" button on case listviews as well on single case page layout. Unless your admin decided to hide it.

If they're notoriously bad at it and you have more than 1 person working on Case - you could think about some enforcing the rule. A validation that you can't change case's status from New unless the owner isn't human for example. Or that you can't close the case unless you own the case. It'd annoy them a bit (fill all the fields needed for closing, hit save, boom, error, need to cancel, change owner, edit again) but after a while they'll get the hint.

But that's the "nasty admin" way, making the system hostile. Start with training, with the value of "My Cases", "My Open Cases" listviews, not just queue queue.

You could also try to always set the owner to whoever edited the case last but that might be tricky if you have some nightly jobs that update them or "inbound email handler" that finds & reopens case for example... Start with training.